# How can I query only certain documents from a firestore collectiongroup, based on the value of a field?

Tags: android, database, google-cloud-firestore

So, I have this firestore database which stores my users and their posts. The posts have this boolean 'available' field which I want to use in order to select which posts are going to appear on my dashboard.
I use collectionGroup to query all the posts, but when trying to check if the 'available' field is 'true' or 'false' using .whereEqualTo("available", "true"), my app runs but the dashboard doesn't load any of the posts and shows a Toast saying "No document found".
This is my code:

```
    private void homePostsRetriever(Context context) {
        String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null ? FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() : null;

        if (userId == null || userId.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "No user id", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        rootRef.collectionGroup("posts").whereEqualTo("available", "true").get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots) {
                for (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : documentSnapshots.getDocuments()) {
                    Post post = new Post();
                    post.setTitle(documentSnapshot.getString("title"));
                    post.setDescription(documentSnapshot.getString("description"));
                    
                    list.add(post);
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "No document found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

It is perfectly working if I try to show all posts, not including *.whereEqualTo()* so this method seems to be the problem..

This is the database's structure:

```
user1 - post1 - postOwner(String) - 'Ted'
              - postTitle(String) - 'Hello everybody'
              - **available**(Boolean) - '**true**'

      - post2 - postOwner(String) - 'Ted'
              - postTitle(String) - 'Afsadf asdfasdf'
              - **available**(Boolean) - 'false'

user2 - post1 - postOwner(String) - 'John'
              - postTitle(String) - 'Dasdas asdfasf'
              - **available**(Boolean) - '**true**'

      - post2 - postOwner(String) - 'John'
              - postTitle(String) - 'Fasd dasdwef'
              - **available**(Boolean) - 'false'
      - post3 - postOwner(String) - 'John'
              - postTitle(String) - 'TRfdsaf fasdfar'
              - **available**(Boolean) - 'false'
```

[UPDATE: I added the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIfvV.png)
I changed the code from "true" to true using .whereEqualTo("available", true) but I get the same result. No post loaded..

[UPDATE2: I added the code img just to be clear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12GcZ.png)

Comment: Without seeing the exact contents of the relevant collections, there's not much we can help with here.

Comment: @DougStevenson hope this is clear enough. thanks for advice

Answer (score 0):

The type of the field has to match between both the client and the server.  There's not enough information here to tell for sure (a screenshot would be better), but your query is asking for documents whose "available" field is set to the exact string "true".  Note that it's asking for a string, not a boolean.  If your documents actually contain boolean field values, they will not be found by the query, because the types don't match.

If your document field "availalble" actually contains booelan values instead of string, you should pass a boolean to the query instead of a string like this:

```
whereEqualTo("available", true)
```

**Not** like you are now, with a string value:

```
whereEqualTo("available", "true")  // the quotes around "true" make it a string
```

Comment: It makes perfect sense but it seems this doesn't fix it anyway..

Comment: So *exactly* does your code do if you update it as I suggested?  By the way, onFailureListener doesn't mean that your query returned no results.  That indicates if the query failed completely, and you should examine the exception to find out what went wrong.

Comment: Added a new img of code just to be clear. Sincerely I have tried using true, and not 'true', several times before posting here.

Comment: Please read my last comment again and answer the question.  I'm asking you to explain what the code is actually **doing** as you observe it from a debugger or debug logging.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what information you want me to provide. I mean I just learned to use the debugger, I used it on these lines of code but I get no hint.